yup typescript image file validation
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as yup from "yup";

interface MyFormType {
  image: FileList | null;
}

const defaultValues: MyFormType = {
  image: null,
};

const validationSchema:yup.ObjectSchema<MyFormType> = yup.object({
  image: yup.mixed<FileList|null>().nullable()
});

const MyForm: React.FC = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm<MyFormType>({
    resolver: yupResolver(validationSchema),
  });

  const onSubmit = (data: MyFormType) => {
    console.log(data); 
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label>
        Image:
        <input type="file" {...register("image")} />
        {errors.image && <p>{errors.image.message}</p>}
      </label>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default MyForm;

I have tried everything I could. I need to upload and image and validate it using yup. I am new to typescript.
I have tried chatgpt and gemini. I am unable to find any example.
